# How find user with empty password in Linux?

Tags: linux

How find user with empty password in Linux?

Answer (score 17):

This is a shorter and more precise version of AndreKR's answer:

```
sudo getent shadow | grep '^[^:]*:.\?:' | cut -d: -f1
```

It has only one call to `cut` and will find entries of any of the forms below:

```
foo:!: ...
bar:*: ...
baz:: ...
```

If you only want truly empty:

```
sudo getent shadow | grep '^[^:]*::' | cut -d: -f1
```

If you have GNU `grep`, you can eliminate `cut` completely:

```
sudo getent shadow | grep -Po '^[^:]*(?=:.?:)'
```

or

```
sudo getent shadow | grep -Po '^[^:]*(?=::)'
```

Answer (score 9):

```
getent shadow | cut -d: -f1-2 | grep ':$' | cut -d: -f1
```

Answer (score 6):

Encrypted password is the second field in /etc/shadow.

If second field is empty, then password empty:

```
awk -F":" '($2 == "") {print $1}' /etc/shadow
```

`!` and `*` is invalid password(user can not login):

```
awk -F":" '($2 == "!" || $2 == "*") {print $1}' /etc/shadow
```

Answer (score 2):

Their entry in `/etc/shadow/` will have no password-hash in it. You'll need to be logged in as root to be able to see them, though.

Answer (score 0):

Has the user "*user*" an empty password ?

```
getent shadow | grep 'user:\$' | cut -d':' -f 2 | grep '\w' -c -m 1
```

return 1 on fail - password is not empty
return 0 on success - a password is set

[linux](/questions/tagged/linux)[debian](/questions/tagged/debian)

Hope this is accurate